# Mongodb lookup different match collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, analytics, lookup

I restate my problem again, to be a little clearer, I need the document numbers that are in A that are not in B, I propose my query that works in parts, I would like to have it all in a single query.

Query 1 returns the information from collection A, with their respective date filters.

Query 2 returns the information from collection B, with its respective date filters and another additional filter.

In Query 3 perform a lookup and an exists to obtain the information that is only in A and not in B.

My wish is to have everything in a single query, but I couldn't locate the $match of the two collections well together with the $lookup and the $exists

Query 1

```
{
    "collection": "receptions",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$match": {
                "$and": [
                    {"ReceptionDate": {"$gt": "{{Fecha Inicio}}","$lt": "{{Fecha Final}}"}},
                    {"UUID": {"$in": [
                                        "21912c",
                                        "585830",
                                        "5bc365",
                                        "7d2136",
                                        "8399f2"
                        ]}}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "DocumentNumber": "$UUID",
                "Date": "$ReceptionDate"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

| Date | DocumentNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 21912c | 2022-08-30T10:37:56.367Z |
| 585830 | 2022-08-30T11:05:40.105Z |
| 5bc365 | 2022-08-30T10:37:56.023Z |
| 7d2136 | 2022-08-30T00:07:29.387Z |
| 8399f2 | 2022-08-30T00:16:28.476Z |

Query 2

```
{
    "collection": "replyacusexmlblobs",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$match": { "$and": [ {"dateNotification": {"$gt": "{{Fecha Inicio}}","$lt": "{{Fecha Final}}"}},
                                { "EventResponse": { "$eq": "recibido" } },
                                {"UUID": {"$in": [
                                                    "21912c",
                                                    "585830",
                                                    "5bc365",
                                                    "7d2136",
                                                    "8399f2"
                        ]}}
                                ] } },
        {
            "$project":{
                "_id":0,
                "DocumentNumber":"$UUID",
                "Date":"$dateNotification"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

| Date | DocumentNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 7d2136 | 2022-08-30T00:07:47.480Z |
| 8399f2 | 2022-08-30T00:16:44.692Z |

Query 3

```
{
    "collection": "receptions",
    "aggregate": [
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "replyacusexmlblobs",
                "localField": "DocumentNumber",
                "foreignField": "DocumentNumber",
                "as": "left_only"
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {"left_only.DocumentNumber": {"$exists": false}}
        }
    ]
}
```

| Date | DocumentNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 21912c | 2022-08-30T10:37:56.367Z |
| 585830 | 2022-08-30T11:05:40.105Z |
| 5bc365 | 2022-08-30T10:37:56.023Z |

Comment: Which field values need to be different for `replyacusexmlblobs` documents to be different than `receptions` documents?

Comment: I'm trying to keep only the field (UUID, that's the name of the field) of the collection (A-receptions). This works with the lookup now what I need is to write a statement that filters the matches of each collection. collection A for the receptions.ReceptionDate field

and this is the match corresponding to collection B replyacusexmlblobs.dateNotification
I don't know if I made myself understand

Comment: Sorry I don't completely understand.  In `"aggregate"` the `"$match"` for `"replyacusexmlblobs.dateNotification"` is before the `"$lookup"`.  Or is `"replyacusexmlblobs"` a field in `receptions` collection?  Without knowing the fields in each collection, it's difficult to understand or suggest anything.

Comment: I restated my idea with data so that it can be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, here's one way to find all the `"UUID"`s from a "search set" in collection `receptions` and then report which of these `"UUID"`s are not in collection `replyacusexmlblobs`.  Date and `"EventResponse": "recibido"` constraints are also handled.

```js
db.receptions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "ReceptionDate": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2022-11-18T23:59:59Z")
      },
      "UUID": {
        "$in": [
          // search set, target UUIDs
          "147369",
          "0c3e19",
          "90cfc2",
          "85961c",
          "1df131",
          "998ca0",
          "badbed",
          "badcab"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { // get all matched UUIDs in one array
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "UUIDs": {"$addToSet": "$UUID"}
    }
  },
  { // lookup matched UUIDs in B collection
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "replyacusexmlblobs",
      "localField": "UUIDs",
      "foreignField": "UUID",
      "as": "raXMLblobUUIDs",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "dateNotification": {
              "$gt": ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00:00Z"),
              "$lt": ISODate("2022-11-18T23:59:59Z")
            },
            "EventResponse": "recibido"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "UUIDs": {"$addToSet": "$UUID"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      // in A, but not B
      "inAnotB": {
        "$setDifference": [
          "$UUIDs",
          {"$first": "$raXMLblobUUIDs.UUIDs"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "inAnotB": [
      "90cfc2",
      "1df131",
      "998ca0"
    ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C5fxzNuJwpx).